# is it possible to add bindings to an element that exists outside of the component?

Tags: svelte

I'm building a browser extension that uses Svelte for it's UI components and in it I am making use of `<video>` elements that live outside of my components (they are part of the hosting page so I don't control their creation), however I am creating instance objects of them and passing them to my component's constructor.

i.e.

```js
const videoElements = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

for (let i = 0; i < videoElements.length; ++i) {
    const videoElement = videoElements[i];
 }

const mySvelteComponent = new ExampleComponent({ target: document.body, props: { video: videoElement } });
```

Is there any way at all to make use of Svelte's many media element bindings like `bind:currentTime`?  I know I can manually bind to these things, I was just curious if there is some svelte mechanism to bootstrap an existing DOM element into a Svelte element.

Comment: "I know I can manually bind to these things" - What do you mean by that?

Comment: @H.B. I mean all the properties on the HTML5 video element are available to inspect and event handlers can be created for those that put out events, my point being that I don't need svelte to accomplish my goals, but I would use svelte if it had a nice way to bind like I'm wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this. Outside of components reactivity is very limited and mainly restricted to using stores and events. You probably will have to manually work with events and the DOM properties here, the code generated by Svelte boils down to this anyway.

(Note that Svelte does not use the `timeupdate` event to update a `currentTime` binding but uses `requestAnimationFrame` instead.)